# javascript passing argument in object

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

Sorry, I'm so newbie not even fully understand even after watch plenty videos and looking in stackoverflow so hard, can't even properly find my problem (passing argument with different object ?)so here I'll just show my code.

```
var Test1 = function(name,gender,job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.job = job;
this.say = function(name ,gender, job){
    console.log(" sup "+ name +", goodluck in" + job);
  }
}
```

this is the `new object` :

```
var budi = new Test1('Budi', 'male', 'developer');
var tono = new Test1('Tono', 'male', 'chef');
```

and I want to pass the `argument` with `object` :

```
budi.say(tono);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have either this implemenation of `say()`

```
  this.say = function(person){
    console.log(" sup "+ person.name +", goodluck in" + person.job);
  }
```

or call it like:

```
budi.say(tono.name, null, tono.job)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do instead

```
this.say = function(/*no arguments here*/ ){
    console.log(" sup "+ this.name +", goodluck in" + this.job);
}
```

If you give the same name arguments to a different scope, they will be considered different variables. Like this you can do:

```
var budi = new Test1('Budi', 'male', 'developer');
budi.say();
```

and it will properly show the strings you used in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the `say()` method read the `name` and `job` from the method parameter (`person` in my example):

```js
var Test1 = function(name, gender, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.job = job;
  this.say = function(person) {
    console.log("sup " + person.name + ", good luck in " + person.job);
  }
}

var budi = new Test1('Budi', 'male', 'developer');
var tono = new Test1('Tono', 'male', 'chef');

budi.say(tono);
```

Comment: thanks ,didnt even think we can create new parameter T_T

Answer (score 0):

hi please review this one

```js
//i change it just for convenient:)
var People = function(name, gender, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.job = job;
  /* you want your `say` function to call another People
  so pass People as the arg, Object with name, gender, job, and another say method*/
  this.say = function(p) {
    /* for string i'd like to use backtick(`) for simplicity and less error phone (ex, space, etc)*/
    console.log(`sup ${p.name}, goodluck in ${p.job}`);
  }
}

var budi = new People('Budi', 'male', 'developer');
var tono = new People('Tono', 'male', 'chef');

budi.say(tono);
```